# How can i change the triangle size to be smaller and change it's location?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Point[] points2 = { new Point(100, 100), new Point(200, 100), new Point(150, 10) };
            e.Graphics.FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), points2);
        }
```

I want to change the triangle location and size. When i change one of the values it's just rotating it.

Comment: When do you wan to change the triangle's location and size? How exactly you want it to be changed?

Comment: I just want to know how to do it. But for now in a button click event. I want that each click will make the triangle smaller by 10 size and move down by 10 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [Triangle.cs](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/FX-1434/FX-1434/1@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/Triangle@cs/1/Triangle@cs), which is what .Net framework uses. Then just make use of `BuildTrianglePoints` method and pass `bounds` to create your triangle.